How to Access and Use an Existing Room Database in Flutter Without Losing Data?
I have an active app on the Google Play Store with a large number of users. I am developing the iOS version of this app with Flutter and want to write the Android side of the app with Flutter as well. I already have a database created with Room Database on the Android side. How can I access and use the existing database in Flutter without losing the data?

One suggestion. You may try including flutter as a module in your current app and use method channels to move your RoomDb data to your desired flutter database. Refer add to app https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app to check how to include flutter in current android app. Later once you have enough people with flutter module, you may replace it with full flutter app. You may try a POC first with this, if there are no other easy ways to achieve your goal.
